# Kotlin by viewModels()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, mvvm, viewmodel

Всем привет! Вопрос такой: by viewModels() вернёт один и тот же экземпляр в разных fragment, или нет?
Если нет, то прошу подсказать, каким образом можно получить один и тот же экземпляр viewModel в родительском и дочернем фрагментах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы в получить `ViewModel` родительского фрагмента, то нужно в дочернем фрагменте этот родительский фрагмент передать в `viewModels` как `ViewModelStoreOwner`:

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels(ownerProducer = ::requireParentFragment)
```

В противном случае будет использован дочерний фрагмент и будет создан новый экземпляр модели